# pywinauto does not find Win32 elements in mixed backend applications under virtualbox

Tags: winapi, virtualbox, win32gui, pywinauto

pywinauto is not finding win32 backend elements that are children of aui backend elements if the script is run in virtualbox

We have a `WinForm ComboBox` that's on invoke pops a `Win32 ComboLBox` with `ListItems` in it. When using pywinauto default approach on local machine
pywinauto is not finding win32 backend elements that are children of aui backend elements if the script is run in virtualbox

We have a `WinForm ComboBox` that's on invoke pops a `Win32 ComboLBox` with `ListItems` in it. When using pywinauto default approach on local machine

```
app.Dialog.ComboLBox.select('myitem')
```

it works perfectly well. When using same code on virtualbox VM (MSEdge on Win10 (x64) from microsoft website), the items under `ComboLBox` object are not seen by pywinauto. *Inspect* lists them, `.ComboLBox.texts()` returns a list of strings, but `.ComboLBox.children()` is empty.

Is there any workaround for such scenarios? I can hardly imagine many usages of automation tools directly on your desktop as all moves towards VMs and cloud these days.

Answer (score 0):

Children of WinForms combo box may be not listed before it’s expanded at least once. This should look the same in Inspect.exe. Method .texts() uses another approach than getting children. Also there is method .select(“...”) that should work fine in both cases. If you strictly need list of children, just do .expand().collapse() before .children().

Of course, this is not related to VirtualBox or any cloud specific things. You’re just lucky to catch this on specific version of .NET Runtime probably.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! It certainly was .Net Runtime related issue. We ended up  having two application objects app (aui start) and app32 (win32 connect) to deal with such sensitive components (mostly menu popup type of elements).

Comment: Cool. If it has resolved your problem, please mark answer as accepted (press gray check box at the left side of the answer; it works with any reputation amount). It's considered polite on StackOverflow.